# Is there a way to get rid of the tab row in atom editor?

Tags: atom-editor, linter

There was a change in base code of Atom.io, so there is a tab row in all panel. It is still bearable in my file tree view, but I do think it is really annoying to have the tab in linter warning panel too.

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[netizen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44698614/2449905) will work, but it will cause a potential problem for you later: if you end up with more than one component in one of your docks, you won't be able to see them, switch between them, close them, or rearrange them.

What you are seeing is that in Atom 1.17, a new UI building block was added, called Docks. You can read more about Docks in the [blog post](http://blog.atom.io/2017/05/16/atom-1-17.html) where they were announced, or in the [deep dive](http://blog.atom.io/2017/05/23/docks-deep-dive.html) written by the Nuclide team.

Instead of specific components written to sit in a special place in the window (such as tree-view, which sat on the left edge), now you have Dock areas: left, bottom, and right. Any component can sit in one of them, and more than one component fits into a dock.

This is like having multiple files in the editor window: you need a way to rearrange them, see all of them, and switch between them. Tabs are the answer to this problem.

Some people find it visually annoying to see the tabs when only one tab exists. Atom offers an option (in the `tabs` package) to change this behavior.

It turns out that this option covers all of the tab bars, not just the tab bar in the file editor.

You can find the option in the settings for the `tabs` package.

- Open Atom preferences
- click "Packages"
- search for "tabs"
- click "Settings" on the "tabs" package
- Un-check "Always Show Tab Bar"

As I mentioned above, this will affect both your editor tabs and the tabs in Docks. When only one tab exists, the tab bar is hidden, and it is shown again when more than one tab exists.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this into yous styles.less file:

```
.atom-dock-inner .bottom .tab-bar { display:none; }
```

Edit: As the comment below from @dan-lowe points, this solution has important drawbacks. It should be applied as a last resort and only to this version both of Atom editor and linter-ui-default, as the docks API is new and prone to changes.

Comment: Note that if you later end up with a bottom dock with more than one tool in it, this will make it difficult to see that, or to switch between the tools.

Comment: @DanLowe Is there any suggestion on safer fix then?

Comment: @cytsunny I didn't realize it before, but yes there is - see the answer I just posted.